# MS word macro vba For Each page

Tags: vba, ms-word

my problem is that I have to run this macro in microsoft office word, which inserts a rectangle at the beginning and at the end of the page
Now, the macro is registered with word and is as follows.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0#, -23.65, 634.05, _
        45.15).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1.14, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VerticalPercentScrolled = 51
    ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0#, 812.4, 623.3, _
        92.45).Select
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VerticalPercentScrolled = 0
End Sub
```

I tried to run a For Each like the following:

```
Dim pages As Page

For Each pages in ActiveDocument
    'here I have pasted the contents of macro1 except the first and last line' 
Next Page
```

My goal is to repeat the recorded macro for each page of the document.
I ask you for help to create this macro because it would save me a lifetime of time thanks.

thank you all

PS: I'm not a native English speaker if you do not understand something ask me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you not use a header and a footer ? On the Insert menu click Header, Footer. 
Then insert a rectangle in the header and the footer. Those rectangles will appear on every page.

The below code will also work. Put the cursor on the first page and execute.

Arrivederci.

```
Dim a
a = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")

For i = 1 To a
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0#, -23.65, 634.05, _
    45.15).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1.14, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VerticalPercentScrolled = 51
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0#, 812.4, 623.3, _
    92.45).Select
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VerticalPercentScrolled = 0
Selection.GoToNext what:=wdGoToPage
Next
```